# MVC WebAPI Call Works Once and Only Once

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have a WebAPI deployed as a Azure Web App  It is .net Framework 4.6.2.  I can call it it once (from a variety of sources, including my JavaScript code and Postman) but the second time it gets called I get the following error:

> {
> "Message": "The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type
> 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.",
> "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'ImportSourceLineActionRequest' from content with media
> type 'application/octet-stream'.",
> "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
> "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
> content, Type type, IEnumerable 1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
> formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
> formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)" }

Some things to note:

- The Content-Type is set in Postman to "application/json"
- The Content-Type is set in my JavaScript to "application/json"

So ... why does my webservice suddenly think I am sending application/octet-stream?

Further, rebooting the Web App fixes the issue ... for one more time.

Javascript code making the call:

```js
const resp = await fetch(callUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: bodyOjbectStr,
    headers:
    {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

API Method that is getting called

```
[HttpPost]
public void DoSomeWork(DoSomeWorkRequestRequest request)
{
    // Do various things
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs (snippet of)

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // config.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.RequestHeaderMapping("Accept","text/html",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase,true,"application/json"));
        }
    }
```

Any help gratefully accepted.

DS

Comment: bodyOjbectStr is a string or an object ?

Comment: @MohitGanorkar a JSONified string of an object.  So, string.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this problem got solved.  It turned out to be a problem with the 2FA we were using.  Not sure why it ever worked once and failed the second time, but when IT made some adjustments to 2FA it all worked.